# Триггер добавления INSERT

Tags: sql-server, запрос, триггер

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
проблема заключается в том что ,в таблице не удается сгруппировать одинаковые строки,т.е. судя по картинке мне нужно получить материал-1,количество-1000,вот код триггера:

```
    USE [ERP]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[Заявка_ЖурналВедомость]    Script Date: 10.05.2016 20:13:00 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Trigger [dbo].[Заявка_ЖурналВедомость] 
ON [dbo].[Журнал_прихода]
FOR insert
AS 
if @@ROWCOUNT=0
SET nocount on
begin
INSERT INTO Ведомость_материалов(Материал,Колличество_на_складе )
SELECT Наименование_детали,sum(Количество)
FROM Журнал_прихода
where  [ID] in(select [ID] from inserted) 
group by Наименование_детали
```

Comment: Странно триггер выглядит. вы всегда добавляете новые строчки с количеством в ведомость. т.е если одна деталь поступает в два прихода то в обоих случаях вы добавите новые записи в ведомость, что скорее всего не верно. Наверно стоит прибавлять кол-во в существующую запись ведомости если запись для данной детали там есть или добавлять новую запись - если ее нет. Имеет смысл использовать merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы бы лучше вместо скрина выложили скрипт DDL создания таблиц.

Допустим, таблицы созданы следующим образом:

```
create table Ведомость_материалов (
    ID                   int primary key,
    Материал             nvarchar(max),
    Количество_на_складе int
)
create table Журнал_прихода (
    ID                   int primary key,
    Наименование_детали  nvarchar(max),
    Количество           int
)
```

Я исхожу из предположения, что столбец `Материал` в одной таблице будет иметь те же значения, что столбец `Наименование_детали` в другой.

Тогда триггер может быть таким:

```
create trigger Заявка_ЖурналВедомость
on Журнал_прихода
for insert
AS
if @@ROWCOUNT = 1
begin
    update Ведомость_материалов
    set Количество_на_складе = Количество_на_складе + (select Количество from inserted)
    where Материал = (select Наименование_детали from inserted)
end
```

Данный триггер срабатывает при *вставке* в одну таблицу, *обновляя* данные в другой таблице.

Наполним таблицу Ведомости материалов начальными значениями:

```
insert Ведомость_материалов values (1, N'болт', 0);
insert Ведомость_материалов values (2, N'шуруп', 0);
```

Теперь, при вставке записей в Журнал прихода:

```
insert Журнал_прихода values (1, N'болт', 100);
insert Журнал_прихода values (2, N'болт', 200);
insert Журнал_прихода values (3, N'шуруп', 1000);
insert Журнал_прихода values (4, N'шуруп', 3000);
```

будет срабатывать триггер и обновлять количество материала на складе.

```
select * from Ведомость_материалов;

ID | Материал | Количество_на_складе  
1  | болт     | 300  
2  | шуруп    | 4000
```

---

Посмотрите [этот](http://datasql.ru/basesql/14.htm) материал про триггеры, там как раз примеры похожи на то, что делаете вы.