# ms sql trigger для подсчета количества

Tags: sql, sql-server, триггер

Есть 2 таблицы в БД: ингридиенты и поставки ингридиентов. У поставок есть тип: поступление(т.е. сложение) и отгрузка (т.е. разность). Нужно сделать 3 тригера (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) которые будут записывать в 3 таблицу данные о том, сколько каждого ингридиента осталось. Лучше чем вот это я добиться не смог

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_supply ON Storages
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @add float
DECLARE @rem float
SELECT @add = SUM(Volume) FROM Storages
    WHERE Type = 0
SELECT @rem = SUM(Volume) FROM Storages
    WHERE Type = 1
INSERT INTO Supply (ingridientid, ingridientname, measure, volume)
SELECT I.Id, I.Name, I.Measure, @add-@rem FROM Ingridients AS I
END
```

Таблица "склада"

```
CREATE TABLE Supply
(
    IngridientId uniqueidentifier,
    IngridientName nvarchar(max),
    Volume float,
    Measure nvarchar(max)
)
```

Таблица поставок

[image: таблица поставок]

Таблица ингридиентов

[image: таблица ингридиентов]

Просьба показать хотябы на 1 тригере, как это сделать.
Спасибо

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что в таблице Supply у Вас будет некий несвязный набор информации об ингридиенте? Возможно туда нужно добавить  информацию о поставке, чтобы в данных об остатках появился некий смысл? И уж точно поле IngridientName лишнее в таблице Supply, Measure, кстати, тоже.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin я хочу чтобы таблица сразу выглядела как "Название" "количество" "объем". например: мука 10 кг, соль 15 кг и т.д.

Comment: Может пригодится: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/522154/184217 . Полезная [ссылка](http://datasql.ru/basesql/14.htm) по триггерам.