# Обновление записи одной таблицы при добавлении записи в другую

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, триггер

Есть 2 таблицы Материалы (номер, название, количество) и Списание (номер, материал, количество, дата).
Как написать триггер, чтобы при добавлении записи в таблицу Списание, изменялась запись с количеством в таблице Материалы.
Проверки на нехватку материалов сделаны в проекте на c#.

Comment: Я бы сделал хранимую процедуру которая, в транзакции, осуществляет вставку в таблицу Списание и обновление в таблице Материалы. Так же не лишним осуществить проверку на нехватку, даже если на клиенте этот процесс уже есть

Comment: А что именно вам непонятно? Синтаксис создания триггера описан в справке по вашей СУБД (её неплохо бы указывать в вопросе), UPDATE тут тривиальный. В чём собственно вопрос?

Comment: Движение материалов так не делают... чревато боком. Остаток мат. ценности - это косвенный атрибут списания, а не прямой атрибут материала...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/522154/184217 - только наоборот